# Sending file using http in android and receiving in jsp

Tags: java, android, jsp, web-applications

I'm new to http file transfer. I want to send a file from android sdcard to server. For that i tried the below code. I converted the bytes to json string and sent it to the server. But I'm unable to receive it on the server side. I'm using jsp on server side. But there should be some efficient way to do this. Please provide me some ideas.

```
 HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://10.0.2.2:8084/httptest");

    try {
        // Add your data
        List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
        String encodedString = convertURL(jsonString);
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("wavfil", encodedString));
        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

        // Execute HTTP Post Request
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        if (entity != null) {

            String responseString = EntityUtils.toString(entity, "UTF-8"); 
            Toast.makeText(this, responseString, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            tv.setText(responseString);
            Log.d("HTTP LOG", responseString);

        }
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    }
```

jsp

```
<%

String value = request.getParameter("wavfil");

byte[] wavByte = value.getBytes();

FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("/TESTFILE.wav");
fos.write(wavByte, 0, wavByte.length);
if (wavByte != null) {
    out.println("Success");
} else {
    out.println("Failed");
}
```

%>

Answer (score 1):

Add below lines

```
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://10.x.x.x:8084/httptest");

try {
    // Add your data
    List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
    String encodedString = convertURL(jsonString);
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("wavfil", encodedString));
    httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
//Create and attach file to the Post
File file = new File("pathto your file"); //replace with actual path
MultipartEntity entity = new MultipartEntity();

httppost.setEntity(entity);

    // Execute HTTP Post Request
    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
    entity.addPart("file", new FileBody(file));
    if (entity != null) {

        String responseString = EntityUtils.toString(entity, "UTF-8"); 
        Toast.makeText(this, responseString, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        tv.setText(responseString);
        Log.d("HTTP LOG", responseString);

    }
} catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
}
```

Comment: Hi.. Is this an efficient way?  or should I use BufferedOutputStream bos =  new BufferedOutputStream(urlc.getOutputStream());
  bos.write(wavdata, 0, wavdata.length);

Comment: that also you can do, but with right Content-type header so that your servlet/jsp will understands the payload

Comment: What does the `MultipartEntity entity = new MultipartEntity();` Mean? I have unable to resolve problem in this line. Please help.